# How do I ask for a correction to an ancient comment?

Tags: discussion

[Replace HTML Table with Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702181/replace-html-table-with-divs)

See the first comment under the question, from user Chad Birch.  It has a malformed link

```
<a href="alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms">Prettier Accessible Forms</a>
```

The software has hyperlinked some, but not all, of that URL.

1. What's the recommended method to ask for a fix for broken but ancient comments?  Fixing that url leads people to useful information
2. Is this a bug that needs to be fixed?  Could the software do a better job of hyperlinking URLs?  Or do people just need to be more careful?

Comment: "How do I ask for a correction to an ancient comment?" - You don't. In cases where it's important (e.g. someboy claims it's perfectly safe to do `rm -rf /` as root), add your own correct comment. In this case, it's just a broken link an auxillary resource, and everybody unable to find out the actual link from the mangled one shouldn't be on the internet anyways. You could add the correct link to save everybody clicking on the broken one a second, but it makes no difference otherwise. And no, this is not a bug, people can mess this up in thousands of ways which SO shouldn't have to handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post a new comment with the correct information.

You can also flag the original comment with a custom explanation, asking for it to be removed: "This comment contains a malformed URL.  I've posted a new comment with the correct link."

Comment: I accepted this answer. I keep forgeting that I can flag comments - it's not an option on the mobile site but I can load the non-mobile site and flag.